# Javascript - assigning dynamic values without eval()

Tags: javascript, json, eval

So, I have 3 variables being passed in:

1. **stats** (JSON object, shown below)
2. **place_type** (string, either "US" or "State")
3. **factor** (string)

I have another variable, **answer**, whose value depends on the other variables. For example, if place_type = "State" and factor = "factor2", then

```
var answer = stats.State.factor2; // equals "E"
```

I'm trying to see if there's a way to dynamically assign a variable **without** needing to use eval().

```
// Simplified, there are many more than 3 factors
var stats = {
    "US": {
        "factor1" : "A",
        "factor2" : "B",
        "factor3" : "C"
    },
    "State": {
        "factor1" : "D",
        "factor2" : "E",
        "factor3" : "F"
    }
}
```

Using eval(), this is how it's done:

```
eval("var answer = stats." + place_type + "." + factor + ";");
```

Is this possible in JS without needing eval() or a ton of different IF loops? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you go:

```
var answer = stats[place_type][factor];
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/simevidas/NsT8Y/

---

Consider putting this in a try-catch block since you chain property accessors. If the `place_type` property does not exist in `stats`, then `stats[place_type]` will return `undefined`, and `undefined[factor]` will throw an error.

```
var answer;

try { 
    answer = stats[place_type][factor];
} catch(e) {}
```

Comment: Before asking, I had tried using answer = stats[place_type][factor], and in the actual code it's place.type ("_" != "."). D'oh!

Comment: @Matt When your code doesn't work, you have to check the error console first.

Answer (score 2):

For this example, it's easy.  The equivalent syntax to

```
var answer = stats.State.factor2;
```

is

```
var answer = stats["State"]["factor2"];
```

and the latter syntax will work with a variable in place:

```
var answer = stats[place_type][factor];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var answer = stats[place_type][factor];
```